# Изменить буквы на последующие в алфавите

Tags: linux, строки, bash

У меня есть строчка в файле:

```
5Gr8L4qetPEsPk8htqjhRK8XSP6x2RHh
```

и нужно как в коде цезаря изменить буквы на последующие в алфавите, т.е. из А сделать В , из G сделать H и т.д.

Comment: [man tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)

Comment: я понимаю что нужна команда tr но мне нужно сразу изменить все буквы на последующие и я не особо понимаю как

Comment: `tr abcd.... bcde...` в мане же все написано

Comment: Он имеет ввиду, что вы **вручную** должны задавать те символы ,на которые хотите поменять
Если нужно изменить буквы abcd на соответственно bcde , то используется команда
**tr abcd bcde**

Comment: ради слравого смысла добавлю, что все символы и вручную прописывать не надо — tr умеет работать с группами... дабы явно не давать ответ, прозрачно намекну — `tr '[0-5]' '[1-4]0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого вы можете использовать символьный массив и цикл.
На языке с++ смена 1 символа на предыдущий и последующий будет выглядеть так:

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std; //вот так лучше не делать, но для малого кода пойдет
int main()
{   char  s;
    cin >> s ;
    cout << "input : " << s << endl;
    cout << "previous :" << char(char(s)-1) << endl;//предыдущее
    cout << " next :" << char(char(s)+1) << endl;//последующее
    }
```

> Если же вам нужно выполнить все на bash, то на сайте https://losst.ru/komanda-tr-v-linux 
>   есть подробная инструкция по использовании утилиты, работающей с текстом

Comment: Вот только для юникода это не реботает.